# assigning unique id and unique name to dynamically created element using global variable

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I tried different methods to assign unique names to my dynamically created `input` fields so that I can access their values in PHP. Came to know that it is possible to declare a global variable in JavaScript that meant that each time I call the `addRow()` function on a button click, the value of the variable wont be reinitialized and so I can use it as an index to the names or id, but I am not able to make it execute.

```
var count = 2;

function addRow() {

  var table=document.getElementById("studenttable");
  var row=table.insertRow(-1);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  

  cell1.innerHTML="<td> <input type='text' **name='nametext+count'" +
    "id='nametext+count'** required  >"; 

  /* also tried..  
  cell1.innerHTML="<td> <input type='text' name='nametext"+count" '" +
    "id='nametext"+count "' required>";
  */

  cell2.innerHTML="<td><div class='dropdown dropdown-dark'>" +
    "<select name='two' class='dropdown-select' >" +
    "<option value=''>Select an option</option><div>" +
    "<option value='1'>Male</option>" +
    "<option value='2'>Female</option></div>" +
    "</option></select></div></td>";

  count++;
}
```

Comment: The code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/T7ZCF/

Comment: the dynamic elements are not being assigned a unique id or name..
i have tried all possible combinations of the quotes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for the `input` (not for the `select`), but I would advise an overall clearer, less error-prone, different approach. It creates nodes the proper way (using `document.createElement()`) instead of setting `innerHTML` - avoiding escaping errors, invalid HTML tags and other common mistakes
.

**[Click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T7ZCF/2/)**.

```
var count = 2;

function addRow() {

    var table = document.getElementById("studenttable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    var ipt = document.createElement('input');
    ipt.setAttribute("type", "text");
    ipt.name = "nametext" + count;      // setting unique NAME
    ipt.id = "nametext" + count;        // setting unique ID
    ipt.setAttribute("required", "true");

    cell1.appendChild(ipt);

    var theDiv = document.createElement('div');
    theDiv.setAttribute("class", "dropdown dropdown-dark");
    var theSelect = document.createElement('select');

    theSelect.name = "select"+count;  // setting unique NAME
    theSelect.id = "select"+count;    // setting unique ID

    theSelect.setAttribute("class", "dropdown-select");
    // option "Select an option"
    var opt0 = document.createElement('option');
    opt0.value = "";
    opt0.text = "Select an option";
    theSelect.appendChild(opt0);
    // option "Male"
    var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
    opt1.value = "1";
    opt1.text = "Male";
    theSelect.appendChild(opt1);
    // option "Female"
    var opt2 = document.createElement('option');
    opt2.value = "2";
    opt2.text = "Female";
    theSelect.appendChild(opt2); 

    theDiv.appendChild(theSelect);
    cell2.appendChild(theDiv);

    count++;
}
```

Comment: k..lemme try this one
but what about the select tag..!! is it possible to assign it a unique id in a similar way..?

Comment: Updated. Hope it is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
cell1.innerHTML="<td> <input type='text' name='nametext+count' id='nametext+count' required  >";
```

To:

```
cell1.innerHTML="<td> <input type='text' name='" + nametext+count + "' id='" + nametext+count + "' required  >";
```

String literals are not interpreted in JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe the asker was trying to bold that section? The buttons do make it seem possible.

Comment: I used to reap the benefits from already asked questions.. new to asking questions on this site. ** was automatically added when i tried to bold the content..!

Comment: :/
@Frits van Campen The button that used to display the new row, has stopped displaying the newly created textbox, as soon as i made the changes..!! what's wrong?
`<a class="button black" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</a>`

Comment: You _change_ `cell1.innerHTML` so whatever was in there is now gone. You can always add by using `+=`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Something is wrong sir. On making these changes includuing this shorthand..
my button is adding blank <td></td> columns to the table row

Comment: Oh, that may be because there is `</td>` missing .. check the HTML string. I copy pasted _your_ code ;)

Comment: yup..they are missing. But in html, isn't the closing tag optional..?
so it should work with or without them.. ?